# Windows 10 install turns off randomly, but Ubuntu runs fine until I use stress -c 8

Tags: windows-10, hardware-failure, ubuntu-16.04

As the title states my Windows 10 install turns off randomly. So far, I have:

1) reinstalled Windows 10 (still doing it, worse than before now)

2) changed out the power supply (which seemed like it was working because windows actually let me get through the memory diagnostic, which found no errors--until the next boot up when it randomly powered off about 5 minutes into reinstalling drivers)

3) tested memory: 100% good to go

4) changed out the GPU

5) installed new noctua fans to rule out airflow issues

I do not believe it is a thermal event because in the past (when playing DOTA 2 in an un-air conditioned apartment with poor heat flow I have had thermal events, and they were usually precluded by a *beep* *beep* *beep* *beep*).

There is no blue screen of death, it just powers off.

How do I rule out what the issue is from here?

EDIT: I just used the command line program stress from the Ubuntu repository to stress out my cpu and I was able to replicate the issue (i.e. get it to shut off)

I typed `stress -c 8` and after a minute or so the computer just shut down. I have thermal paste en route so I will try to clean the processor and reapply thermal paste and see if this fixes the issue.

If it does not, how do I rule out that it is the cpu and not the motherboard?

Comment: Is this a computer you built yourself? If not, what is the brand and model?

Comment: Yes. I actually JUST opened it and removed the corsair h105 from the processor and see that the mounts weren't seated properly. I reapplied the paste about a month ago, but only started putting the cpu under real load over the paste week as I started gaming again. The thermal paste was only spread to 75% of the surface and I doubt it was >95% contact given how off one of the mounts was. So, I replaced the mounts with backups. So CPU overheating is likely the main issue. I have thermal paste coming via amazon same day and it should be here within the next hour or so. I will update accordingly!

Comment: What is your CPU and power supply? It's hard to say so far but in my experience its the power supply. Yes I know you changed it. It wouldn't be the first time I had issues with multiple PSUs in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be the case that the water cooler (Corsair h105) wasn't seated perfectly on the CPU. I cleaned it and reapplied thermal paste last month and failed to seat the cooler on the mounts appropriately--so it was not sitting flush. but only started putting the CPU under load over the past week or so (when the problem started). There was also not enough paste on the cpu.

The moral of the story: make sure your cpu is mounted on a cooler appropriately and use enough thermal paste.